# Как называется и работает такое динамическое выделение памяти?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

class T
{
    int x;
  public:
    T() { std::cout << "constr\n"; }
    ~T() { std::cout << "destr\n"; }
};

int main (void)
{
  char *buf = new char[sizeof(T)]; //13 line
  T *t = new(buf) T;

  t->~T();
}
```

Что это за выделение памяти такое `new(buf)`? То есть память выделяется в строчке 13, а потом в строчке 14 не выделяется новая память под объект типа `T`, а берется уже выделенная память из той, на которую указывает `buf`. То есть такой способ занимает меньше действий, потому как можно раз выделить много памяти и потом использовать её с помощью `new(buf)` при динамическом выделении объектов. Если это так, то указатель будет указывать на следующий свободную ячейку памяти выделенного участка, когда будет к примеру ещё одно выделение `T *t2 = new(buf) T;`, то есть buf указывает на участок памяти размером с размер класса T и по этому перезапишет память, на которую указывает `*t`. И ещё не понятно как это реализовано. Так как `new` - это оператор, то наверное есть его перегруженная версия, которая принимает указатель на уже выделенную память и вторым параметром объект, который нужно выделить в ней.
Вообщем это все догадки и возможно я кардинально не прав по этому поводу. Так что лучше всего было бы, если бы вы написали как это называется, что бы можно было хоть почитать где нибудь об этом способе или объяснили так, как вы считаете нужным.

Comment: [Placement new][1]
  [1]: http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_(C%2B%2B)#Placement_new

Comment: @mzarb, почему Вы решили, что

    можно раз выделить много памяти и потом использовать её с помощью new(buf) при динамическом выделении объектов.

Откуда эта многократность?

На самом деле 

    T *t = new(buf) T;

предписывает создать **один** экземпляр объекта `T` в памяти по адресу, содержащимся в указателе `buf`.

Т.о. динамическая память для `T` в этом `new` **не выделятся** и деструктор надо вызывать вручную, до delete [] buf.

Comment: @avp: может быть, ТС имел в виду выделение большой арены и создание объектов на ней по разным смещениям (техника, используемая для ускорения выделения памяти).

Comment: @VladD, мало ли что он имел в виду. Пример-то совсем конкретный с памятью под один экземпляр.

Comment: @avp: это да, память ровно на один объект.

Comment: @VladD,@avp, как пользоваться в принципе было понятно, но я не пойму как это работает и уже много чего перечитал, но или не там читал или не переварил. То есть, к примеру в этом коде `new T`, сначала выделяется память и потом возвращается указатель на нее и вызывается конструктор, но почему конструктор инициализирует поля класса на куче, откуда он знает что нужно не на стеке, а на куче? Кто или какая функция за это отвечает? Ведь new просто вернет указатель на выделенную память, а дальше конструктор не понятно как инициализирует объект именно в этой памяти.

Comment: >> но почему конструктор инициализирует поля класса на куче, откуда он знает что нужно не на стеке, а на куче?

конструктор инициализирует класс там, где дали ему память. Ему все равно, какую память дали. Для обычного конструктора где выделять память, решает компилятор, который руководствуется стандартом. 

>> а дальше конструктор не понятно как инициализирует объект именно в этой памяти.

в самом простом приближении, инициализация - это просто записывание нулей.

Стековая память и память в куче ничем, кроме адреса не отличается. Никто не мешает сделать кучу на стеке.

Comment: @mzarb, в коде 

    T *t = new(buf) T;

память НЕ выделяется. Этот код говорит компилятору, что создавать экземпляр T надо по ПЕРЕДАВАЕМОМУ в аргументе `new()` адресу. 


Об этом уже говорили в комментарии. 

А new вернет адрес buf (можете проверить).

Заодно посмотрите адреса с

    char buf[sizeof(T)];

Comment: А как вычисляется размер? Ведь во всех прототипах `new` есть параметр `size_t size`, но к примеру в таком коде `new T`, я же его явно не передаю, то есть компилятор сам делает sizeof(T) и передает в оператор функцию new? Это исключения или есть возможность делать подобное и с другими функциями?

Comment: @mzarb: Да, это магия компилятора. Когда вы говорите `new T`, происходит на самом деле две вещи: (1) вызывается глобальный оператор `new` с параметром sizeof(T) (ну или `operator new` для класса, если он перегружен), (2) вызывается конструктор `T` со значением `this`, равным адресу, полученному при выделении памяти. Если вы вызываете `new(buf) T`, первый шаг пропускается.

Comment: @avp, >что создавать экземпляр T надо по ПЕРЕДАВАЕМОМУ в аргументе new() адресу.  

 а как этот адрес подставится между "A" и "()"? Здесь же A() - это не вызов конструктора как обычной функции, а создание объекта типа А и вызов конструктора без параметров (), то есть между ними должен подставится адрес, который вернет new и как же он туда подставится, если он расположен до A(). Такую подстановку можно как-то объяснить?

Comment: @KoVadim  

>инициализация - это просто записывание нулей.  
То есть создание объектов `T t;` или `T t();`, гарантирует инициализацию их нулями? И что именно будет инициализировано нулями, всего его поля?

Comment: Здесь все сложнее. В случае `T t()` будут вызваны конструкторы по умолчанию для всех полей. В случае int будет просто записан ноль, в случае std::string - будет вызван его конструктор (он внутри заметно сложнее).

Если же идет вызов `T t`, то здесь два варианта. Если у объекта определен конструктор по умолчанию (`T()`), то он и будет вызван. Если же его нет, то никто ничего не будет обнулять. Вот три полезные ссылки [1](http://demin.ws/blog/russian/2009/03/15/constructor-call-in-cpp/), [2](http://goto-cpp.blogspot.com/2012/04/new.html) и [3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/620137/).

Comment: @mzarb,

        а как этот адрес подставится между "A" и "()"? 
        .....
        Такую подстановку можно как-то объяснить?

до конца не понимаю, что Вы имеете в виду. Могу только сказать, что *никто ничего никуда* в этом случае *не подставляет*.

Компилятор для обращения к полю `x` созданного экземпляра `t` класса T будет генерить машинные команды, которые используют адрес в переменной buf. 

Во втором случае (пример в моем ответе) компилятор знает адрес переменной s.f2, относительно начала стекового фрейма  и будет генерить соответствующие команды.

Вот суть всей этой катавасии.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[@mzarb](/users/11390/mzarb), на самом деле никакой магии тут нет. Все довольно просто. Это Вы наделяете язык/компилятор какими-то особыми свойствами.

Разберите пример Вашей (немного измененной) программы.

```
avp@avp-xub11:~/hashcode$ cat mzarb.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

class T
{
    int x;
  public:
    T() { std::cout << "constr\n"; }
    ~T() { std::cout << "destr\n"; }
  void setX(int v) { x = v; }
};

int main (void)
{
  struct {
    char f1[2];
    char f2[10];
  } s;
  strcpy (s.f2,(char *)"1234");
  std::cout << "f2 before: " << s.f2 << '\n';

  T *t = new(s.f1) T;

  std::cout << "f2 after: " << s.f2 << '\n';
  t->setX('z');
  std::cout << "f2 again: " << s.f2 << '\n';

  std::cout << "f2 offset: " << s.f2+2 << '\n';

  t->~T();
}
avp@avp-xub11:~/hashcode$ g++ mzarb.cpp 
avp@avp-xub11:~/hashcode$ ./a.out 
f2 before: 1234
constr
f2 after: 1234
f2 again: 
f2 offset: 34
destr
avp@avp-xub11:~/hashcode$
```

Видите, все предельно прозрачно. Никто ничего не проверяет. А рассуждения о надежности и безопасности это в реальности "развод лохов".

Да, крестовый компилятор делает много проверок и для них язык заставляет Вас писать (и изучать) кучу лишнего.

Comment: >`T *t = new(s.f1) T;`
Тут объект на стеке создается?

Comment: @mzarb, да в стеке.

Обратите внимание, 

    f2 after: 1234


никакой инициализации памяти объекта (реально одного int) не происходит.

Comment: @avp  
>Компилятор для обращения к полю x созданного экземпляра t класса T будет генерить машинные команды, которые используют адрес в переменной buf.  
Спасибо, это тоже не знал. Но вот как адрес, который вернул new, воспринимается как объект? К примеру `код new T()` будет выглядеть как "адрес_который_вернул_new((T()))", но для создания объекта нужен же и тип перед самим объектом, то есть должно быть что-то такое "T адрес_объекта_который_вернул_new()", по аналогии с созданием обычного объекта без new "T t()", где на месте "t" был бы адрес в случае создания через new.

Comment: @mzarb, адрес, который вернет `new` будет записан в переменную `t`.

Как объект его воспринимаете Вы и компилятор С++ в процессе компиляции текста программы. 

Создание объекта - это очень громкие слова, за которыми стоит выделение участка памяти нужного размера (в некоторых случаях ее инициализация) и генерация команд вызова подходящего конструктора.

Во время исполнения никаких сведений о типах (в нашем случае) нет. Все адреса это просто целые числа длиной 32 бита (или 64 на 64-bit компьютере).

--

Да, IMHO надо сначала освоить Си и ассемблер (и на этом можно остановиться).

Comment: @avp  
>new "T t()"  
Здесь я имел ввиду не `new T t()`, а - `T t()`. Просто не понятно, что происходит после того как new вернул адрес, то есть как будет выглядеть код(с точки зрения C++, а не глубже), в котором конструктор вызывается с этим адресом, а не то, что происходит в конструкторе после вызова.